# Crystal Reports Hanging on server 2008 r2

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

Crystal Reports are hanging from all windows servers 2008 R2.  When I launch the report in any browser it just hangs, no error message is ever displayed.

I installed it on my local IIS 7.5 and it works fine.

- I have un-installed windows updates since it last worked (weeks ago)
- Updated CR to the 13.0.0.8
- Tried creating a new website from scratch on the server
- Copied the crystalreportviewiers13 to the asp_net\system_web\4_0_30319
- There is a printer installed on the server, other posts have suggested this.

I can't re-create the problem locally on my dev machine, I've tried re-installing etc.

The dev machine points to the db and I know the report isn't even getting that far as I cannot see the report hitting the db server.

On my local dev machine I'm running the app pool as the same user as the dev environment, it all works fine.

The site is running under .net 4.0.

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), on the server the report was looking for the same default printer I have on my machine where the report was developed.

Adding this printer to the server the report is served as expected, even though it takes a while.  Although this is not the ideal solution it solves the problem.

I think the best option in the future for this is to make sure the default printer selected in the report is the Microsoft XPS Document Writer.  To do this go to the report in the designer->Design->Page-Setup and select.